# IN statement from CASE result inside Where clause Oracle

Tags: oracle, case

I have a sample of the table and problem I am trying to solve in Oracle.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
id_field number
,status_code number
,desc1 varchar2(15)
);

INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES (1,240,'desc1');
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES (2,242,'desc1');
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES (3,241,'desc1');
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES (4,244,'desc1');
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES (5,240,'desc2');
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES (6,242,'desc2');
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES (7,245,'desc2');
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES (8,246,'desc2');
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES (9,246,'desc1');
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES (10,242,'desc1');

commit;

SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE status_code IN CASE WHEN desc1 = 'desc1' THEN (240,242)
                          WHEN desc1 = 'desc2' THEN (240,245)
                            END
```

Basically I need to select a subset of status codes for each condition.
I could solve this with separate statements but the actual table I am doing this on has multiple descriptions and would result in around 20 unioned queries.

Any way to do this in one statement like I have attempted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that a `CASE` statement can only return one value (corresponding to one column in the result set).  However, you can achive this in your `WHERE` clause without using a `CASE` statement:

```
WHERE (desc1 = 'desc1' AND status_code IN (240,242)) OR
      (desc1 = 'desc2' AND status_code IN (240,245))
```

Comment: thanks I tried this originaly but without the brackets. thanks heaps

Answer (score 1):

I like Tim answer better, but at least in postgres you can do this. *Couldnt try it on oracle*

[Sql Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7f870/5)

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE CASE WHEN desc1 = 'desc1' THEN status_code IN (240,242)
           WHEN desc1 = 'desc2' THEN status_code IN (240,245)
      END
ORDER BY  desc1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id_field | status_code | desc1 |
|----------|-------------|-------|
|        1 |         240 | desc1 |
|        2 |         242 | desc1 |
|       10 |         242 | desc1 |
|        5 |         240 | desc2 |
|        7 |         245 | desc2 |
```